# Test Rails CRUD methods with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec-rails

I have a `Post` object in my Rails app that I am trying to write request tests for. I keep getting an `ArgumentError: unknown keyword: post` error. Here is my request spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "Post", :type => :request do
  describe '#create' do
    it "creates a Post and redirects to the Post's page" do
      get "/posts/new"
      expect(response).to render_template(:new)

### This is where the error is happening. On the `post` method.
      post "/posts", :post => {:title => "My Post", :content => "My post content"}

      expect(response).to redirect_to(assigns(:post))
      follow_redirect!

      expect(response).to render_template(:show)
      expect(response.body).to include("Post was successfully created.")
    end

    it "does not render a different template" do
      get "/posts/new"
      expect(response).to_not render_template(:show)
    end
  end
end
```

I referenced the code from the [Relish RSpec Docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-8/docs/request-specs/request-spec#specify-managing-a-widget-with-rails-integration-methods)

Comment: What Rails version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Rails 5.1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API has changed so now you will need to pass in your post to `params`

```
post "/posts", :params => { :post => {:title => "My Post", :content => "My post content"} }
```

Notice that your reference specifies @rails_pre_5, while the example directly below it specifies @rails_post_5

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I don't know how I missed that.